# Is there a system / btrfs tool whick will provide me with the record location for a specific inode number in a btrfs volume?

Tags: btrfs, utilities, inode

I want to find the location of the record data for a specific inode. Is there a system tool or a btrfs tool which will provide me with at least it's bloc number ?